# Changing the format of a text file when running Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to using batch files so I am stumped. I have a simple query using psexec that remotely checks the registry of several computers. The query tells me what version of Internet Explorer is installed.

I output the results to a .txt file, but I want the output to line up the IP address with the results so I get a single line and it's easier to read. Is this possible? Here is my "code" and the resulting output:

```
psexec \\@agents.txt -s reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v svcVersion >test.txt
```

`@agents.txt` is simply a list of IP addresses. The result of test.txt is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
    svcVersion    REG_SZ    11.0.9600.18449


HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
    svcVersion    REG_SZ    11.545.10586.0


HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
    svcVersion    REG_SZ    11.545.10586.0

\\10.10.10.10:

\\10.10.10.11:

\\10.10.10.12:
```

So 10.10.10.10 is the first result and has IE version 11.0.9600.18449. Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this PowerShell script. It retrieves the Internet Explorer version from one or more computers:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-IEVersionps1-44863ea8

It has numerous advantages over shell script (batch):

1. Retrieves the version information directly from the `iexplore.exe` file
2. Supports multiple computers
3. Object-based output makes it easy to create a CSV file containing results